# Table View Not Reloading from texfield in Parent View - Swift 3, Algolia Search

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Ok, I am using Algolia Search as an indexing service for my IOS app to Index my Firebase Database and add search functionality.  The code they provide in their docs uses a search bar.  However, due to the difficulty of customizing the search bar, I decided to see if I could use a text field instead.  What I have so far with the text field works successfully.  The **textfield.text** gets passed into the **Alogolia Search function** and the results are returned successfully and accurately to whatever is typed into the textbox.  I am using NSNotification to pass the **String - textfiled.text** to the child view which is the view of the search results and also where the Algolia Search Function is.  I have a picture below that illustrates this.

[image: Parent View and Child Table View]

**The Problem:**
For some reason whenever I use the textfield to search the results get returned in the console but the tableview **does not reload**.  However, whenever I set the search query in the **viewDidLoad()** the tableView is reloaded and displays the correct results in the cells.

I've tried updating the tableview on the Main Thread but that does not seem to work. I believe there is a timing issue with the code, but I'm not completely sure

**My Code:**

```
import UIKit
import AlgoliaSearch
import SwiftyJSON
import AFNetworking

class SearchView: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, 
UISearchControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var businessSearch = [Business]()
var businessIndex: AlgoliaSearch.Index!
let query = Query()
var searchId = 0
var displayedSearchId = -1
var loadedPage: UInt = 0
var nbPages: UInt = 0
var searchText = String() *** THE VALUE PASSED TO THE SEACRH FUNCTION


// var businesses = [Business]()

var searchController: UISearchController! 


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                        selector: #selector(SearchView.handleTextChange(_:)),
                        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: handleTextChangeNotification),object: nil)


    // Search controller
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    //searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    // Add the search bar
    //tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
    //definesPresentationContext = true
    //searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    let apiClient = Client(appID: "APPID", apiKey: "API KEY")
    self.businessIndex = apiClient.index(withName: "businessSearch")
    query.hitsPerPage = 15
    query.attributesToRetrieve = ["businessName","Address","Score","businessType","hours","city"]



}


*** WHERE TEXTFIELD KEY STROKES ARE OBSERVED AND SAVED
func handleTextChange(_ myNot: Notification) {
    if let use = myNot.userInfo {
        if let text = use["text"] {
            searchText = text as! String ***WHERE SEARCH VALUE IS SET
            print(searchText)

            *** WHERE THE SEARCH FUNCTION IS RUN
            query.query = searchText  
            let curSearchId = searchId

            self.businessIndex.search(self.query, completionHandler: {
                (data, error) in

                if curSearchId <= self.displayedSearchId || error != nil {
                    print("problem #1")
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error 1")
                    return // Newest query already displayed or error
                }

                // Decode JSON
                guard let hits = data!["hits"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return }
                guard let nbPages = data!["nbPages"] as? UInt else { return }
                self.nbPages = nbPages
                print(hits)
                var tmp = [Business]()
                for hit in hits {
                    tmp.append(Business(json: hit))
                }

                //Reload view with the new data
                //self.businessSearch = tmp

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    self.businessSearch = tmp
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                })


            })
            self.searchId += 1

        }

    }


}

func loadMore() {
    if loadedPage + 1 >= nbPages {
        return // All pages already loaded
    }
    let nextQuery = Query(copy: query)
    nextQuery.page = loadedPage + 1
    businessIndex.search(nextQuery, completionHandler: {
        (data , error) in

        if nextQuery.query != self.query.query || error != nil {
            print("problem #2")
            return // Query has changed
        }

        self.loadedPage = nextQuery.page! as UInt
        let json = JSON(data!)
        let hits: [JSON] = json["hits"].arrayValue
        var tmp = [Business]()
        print("...\(hits.count)")
        for record in hits {
            tmp.append(Business(json: record.dictionaryObject! as [String : AnyObject]))
        }
        // Display the new loaded page
        self.businessSearch.append(contentsOf: tmp)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

 *** TABLE VIEW SET UP
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return businessSearch.count
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:indexPath as IndexPath) as! SearchCell
    let cellData = self.businessSearch[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = cellData.businessName
    cell.addressLabel.text = "1234 Main St."
    cell.hoursLabel.text = "9:00 AM - 10:00 PM"
    cell.reviewCountLabel.text = "45 Reviews"
    cell.backgroundImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "samplebg")



    if (indexPath.row + 5) >= businessSearch.count {
        loadMore()
    }

    return cell 
}


deinit{
    self.searchController = nil
}
```

Comment: Hmm I don't see an obvious reason as to why you're getting this bug. First thing as an fyi, the completionHandler is happening on `DispatchQueue.main`. Now let's get to the issue: If you put a breakpoint inside the `DispatchQueue`, can you get there? can you also put a breakpoint at the `numberOfRowsInSection` and see if the `count` changes when you enter a new text in the textField? is the `print(hits)` properly printing the right hits? Let me know and I can try to help you from there.

Comment: For those interested in the solution, OP wrote a neat tutorial [here](https://discourse.algolia.com/t/tutorial-using-a-textfield-in-swift-3-for-search-instead-of-a-search-controller/1308). Thanks again @ethanfox27 !

Comment: Have you implemented the instant search in your app ? @ethanfox27

Comment: @VamsiS Yes I have

Comment: i implemented using instant search not algolia search client but i am unable to implement it using instant search and later i tried algolia search client then i got it but do u have any instant search demo implementation normal displaying i had done but i am unable to filter search results by passing query using instant search but by using algolia search client later i got it @ethanfox27